# PHP Submit form to self with files on form

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, form-submit

I've done forms that submit to self for none javascript validation of fields, now i'm looking for a way to upload a file the same way, the form submits to itself and the code works for everything except the file.

I'm not 100% sure why this is happening, it's a post form and the input file is called image and basically i'm using `$_FILES['image']` to check the file but it reloads empty without a file and the form isn't validating the file and acts like nothing was on that field.

Anybody has experience with this? I use MAMP for php test and i thought maybe it had to do with it, but i later uploaded it  my server and didn't work either, thanks.

Comment: Displaying the form again, the browser won't put the previous file in there. So you "loose" the file. You would need some kind of session management to keep successful uploads already on the server while offering the form again with the errors on the *other* (non-file) inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `encytype="multipart/form-data"` added as the attribute of form tag.

```
<form action="" method="post" encytype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: hey, yes i got that already as well, i normally submit the form to another php file so i usually use that encytype, thanks.